# Kick Command (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a kick command so that if the reason is nothing, then it says "no reason" instead of none. Don't ask why.

Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason: str):
  if reason is None:
    await user.kick()
    await ctx.send(f"**{user}** has been kicked for **no reason**.")
  else:
    await user.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"**{user}** has been kicked for **{reason}**.")
```

And here's the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command kick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 847, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 784, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 699, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 535, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: reason is a required argument that is missing.
```

I don't understand why it says that "reason is a required argument that is missing" because I said that if reason is None it would say no reason?

Comment: You haven't set `reason` to be an optional parameter (i.e. it needs a default value). You can do `reason: str=None` instead of `reason: str` in the parameters

Answer (score 3):

If you assign `None` to the `reason`, then you can check it. For example `reason = None`. After that you can check in the commmand if the reason is **None**. Here is the code:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
  if not reason:
    await user.kick()
    await ctx.send(f"**{user}** has been kicked for **no reason**.")
  else:
    await user.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"**{user}** has been kicked for **{reason}**.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because your function looks like this:

```
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason: str):
```

Reason is not optional here, so it is a `required argument`. That means that calling this function without that argument will result in an error. Adding in a default value makes it optional.

```
def function(requiredArgument, optionalArgument=defaultValue)
```

In this case, `defaultValue` should be `None`. Now, when you don't pass in anything for that argument, it's default value will be used. That way, you no longer *have to* add a reason.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple just write:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def kick(self, ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has been kicked for {reason}!')
```